# Dagger how to inject one implementation in code

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am Android developer and new to clean architecture.

I have a `usecase1` class that is injected with a `Repository` instance via constructor injection:

```
 public class usecase1 {

    public final Repository repository;
    @Inject
    public usecase1(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    List<String> getlist(){
        return repository.list();
    }
}
```

in database layer I have 2 implementation. one for local and one for internet fetch data.

in dagger I create 2 method with @named annotation for online and offline and return implementation. this is module code:

```
 @Provides
@Singleton
@Named("Online")
Repository getRepository(){
  return new OnlineRepository();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("Offline")
Repository getRepository(){
    return new OfflineRepository();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("Offline")
Usecase1 getusecase1offline(@Named("Offline")Repository repository){
    return new usecase1(repository);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("Online")
Usecase1 getusecase1online(@Named("Online")Repository repository){
    return new usecase1(repository);
```

my problem is how to inject Appropriate dependency. and how to say to dagger that inject offline or online usecase.

Comment: can you share your Module and Component code?

Comment: @homerman i think not important those class. in my viewmodel constructor, i inject repository. how i say to dagger that which repository to inject offline or online.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the other bits I asked about, I can only offer so much advice that doesn't amount to guessing. In other words, help me help you.

in the `Module` that provides the `usecase1` instance(s), you might do something like this:

```
@Module
class MyModule {
  // if you're provided qualified references for the usercase1 class
  // itself, then you could provide two implementations that use the same
  // qualifier as the Repository types they depend on (or choose another 

  @Provides @Named("Online")
  Repository provideOnlineUsecase1(@Named("Online") repository) {
    return new usecase1(repository);
  }

  @Provides @Named("Offline")
  Repository provideOfflineUsecase1(@Named("Offline") repository) {
    return new usecase1(repository);
  }

  // ...alternatively, if you're not providing qualified references of
  // usecase1 you can simply pick one. this might be the case if you're 
  // doing some manual testing and don't mind periodically rebuilding the
  // project switching between "Online" and "Offline":

  @Provides 
  Repository provideUsecase1(@Named("Offline") repository) {
    return new usecase1(repository);
  }
}
```

The key point is that your qualified `Repository` instances are bound by referring to them in a consuming provider method as parameters annotated with the same named qualifier.

in other words, since `OfflineRepostiory` is provided with the @Named("Offline") qualifier, another provider that needs it can refer to it by declaring it as a parameter of type `Repository` annotated with @Named("Offline").

As an aside... broadly speaking, it seems like your types (`usecase1`, `Repository`) are of the nature that commonly need only be a singleton instance, but I don't see any scoping modifiers in your code snippet.

Keep in mind that sharing a little more about your problem may yield better feedback. I hope I've been of some help.

** Update **

From your comment it seems like you're wondering how to switch between two different `Repository` implementations based on a dynamically computed value (like network connection status). In that case, I would probably do something like this:

```
@Module
class MyModule {
  @Provides @Named("Online") 
  Repository provideOnlineRepository() {...}

  @Provides @Named("Offline") 
  Repository provideOfflineRepository() {...}

  @Provides
  Supplier<Boolean> provideIsConnectedSupplier() {...}

  @Provides
  Repository provideUseCase(
    Supplier<Boolean> isConnectedSupplier,
    @Named("Online") Repository onlineRepository,
    @Named("Offline") Repository offlineRepository) {

      return new usecase1(
        isConnectedSupplier, 
        onelineRepository, 
        offlineRepository);
  }
}
```

In this setup, `usecase1` is given an object that it can interrogate to see if it has a network connection, and then use the `Repository` that corresponds to the result. this has the benefit that you can develop and test all your components independently, and you're using Dagger just to assemble them all (rather than putting switching logic in your module).

from a design perspective you can do much better than this (e.g. using streams), but hopefully this is enough to inspire some ideas.

Comment: sorry, i edit my answer. i meant that in viewmodel that i inject use case how to inject appropriate instance. i have a condition that is connectivity status.do i can use connectivity status in module. perhaps i can with use use that make a factory .and return appropriate use case

Comment: Ok I think I understand. See the update to my answer. Let me know if this isn't what you're talking about.

Comment: very thanks, of course, It came to my mind. but problem is we pass two instance of repository to domain layer that is not good, perhaps tomorrow we have 3 or 4 repository. i use rxjava to implement this scenario and not bad. But it didn't sit well with me

Comment: I'd probably push that connection-based switching logic into a single `Repository` that acts as a facade over `OnlineRepository` and `OfflineRepository`, that or just merge those two into a single `Repository` that manages itself based on connection status. that way your use cases don't have to take connection status into account (to your point).